# Divergent sequence is not cauchy proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $s_n = \sqrt n$. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}
|s_{n+1} − s_{n}| = 0$,

but that $(s_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

choose $ \epsilon >0 $ want to show there exist's an N s.t for all n>N implies that $|s_{n+1} − s_{n}|< \epsilon $

$ |\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n|$ clearly this is always positive.

$(\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n) \frac{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}= \frac{n+1 - n}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt {n} + \sqrt n}=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt {n}}< \epsilon$

$\frac{1}{2\epsilon}< \sqrt n \implies \frac{4}{\epsilon^2}<  n$

FP: Let $N =\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}$ for all n>N implies that $n> \frac{4}{\epsilon^2} \implies {\epsilon^2}> \frac{4}{n} \implies {\epsilon}> \frac{2}{\sqrt n} \geq \sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n =|s_{n+1} − s_{n}|$

this feels oddly wrong becaus i wasnt using what the limit value was? i believe i also want to show somehow that $s_n = \sqrt n$ is unbounded but am not sure how to do so, as i believe that would imply its not Cauchy?

Comment: For one impressed you managed to write a post that is 3 characters long but w.o context that literally means nothing to me.

Comment: You were using the limit value, it is $0$. Showing that $s_n$ is unbounded is a good idea. Show that for any $M > 0$, there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\sqrt{n} > M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you proved that Cauchy sequences are bounded? Equivalently unbounded implies not Cauchy.  That's a good proof to be able to fire off and is quite direct from definition.

You can show that $\sqrt n$ is unbounded by contradiction.  Assume $s_n < M$ for all $M$. But then $N = 4M^2$ is such that $s_N = \sqrt{N} = 2M > M$.

Once you are convinced that the sequence is unbounded, you can also just use the first line you wrote to show the limit:

$$|\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n| = (\sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt n) \frac{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}= \frac{n+1 - n}{\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt {n} + \sqrt n}=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt {n}}$$

This shows precisely that $s_n \rightarrow \infty$ implies $|s_{n+1} - s_n| \rightarrow 0$.

So you've already done most of the work! As you suspected, you should just work through the proof that Cauchy implies bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You've succeeded in showing $|s_{n+1} - s_n| \to 0$.  To prove the sequence is not Cauchy use the rationalization and consider

$$|s_{2n} - s_n| = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}(\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}) = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}} > \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n} + \sqrt{2n-1}}$$